# Really simple UPDATE query not working

Tags: mysql

Just starting out with SQL, and I'm attempting to do a simple UPDATE statement. For some reason it isn't working though. The code is as follows

`UPDATE batting SET BA = (h/ab);`

After it runs it returns a division by zero error.

Whenever I use a simple select statement with that formula it works fine. What do I need to do?

Comment: Data type of h and ab ????

Comment: hits and at-bats from the Lahman baseball database. It's not my own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because value of ab is 0 for some records. To skip those recods, you can use `CASE` statement with update, e.g.:

```
UPDATE batting   
SET BA = CASE  
             WHEN ab = 0 THEN BA
             ELSE h/ab
         END 
WHERE //condition
```

Comment: You can accept my answer as correct answer if it helped you :)

Comment: This can also be written as `update batting set ba=IF(ab=0;ba;h/ab) where ...` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)). And yes, @saberfan7, please give credits to Darshan.

Comment: Oh no problem @Darshan. I clicked the checkmark, is that it?

Comment: Yes, @saberfan7. You can also consider hitting the up-arrow if you found his answer useful (and not only the best one given). Tickle the icons with your mouse to see what they mean. ;-)